# why std::map has a member function called count?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I'm learning C++ and apparently a way of checking if a particular key exists in a `std::map` is using the member function `count`.

My first though was: Aren't the keys supposed to be unique? And checking the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) indeed they are unique, so count will either return 0 or 1.

Isn't it a bit counter-intuitive to call it `count`? Why not `exist`?

To me count makes sense in a list where you expect a number of occurrences of an element, but if the method is only allowed to return 1 or 0 it doesn't make sense to me.

Am I missing something? Is there a reason to call it `count` or it's just a bad naming?

Comment: It is just for consistency with `std::multimap`.

Comment: Are 0 and 1 not numbers of occurrences?

Comment: All associative containers need to have `count`.  It makes writing generic code easier.

Comment: And you want the consistency because of duck-typing for templates, which doesn't work so well when everything quacks a little differently.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343130/why-does-stl-set-have-count-when-all-elements-are-supposed-to-be-unique also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534931/why-is-the-c-stl-set-containers-count-method-thus-named also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532550/why-does-stdset-not-have-a-contains-member-function/42532783

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little like using a method `.numberOfWives()` to determine if you are married or not. Does the job and helps build generic code.

Sure, it's *normally* 0 or 1 (`std::map`), but it could be more than one (`std::multimap`, or polygamous jurisdictions).

Comment: Somewhat outdated and inaccurate though :) This should at least be locale-dependent I guess.

Comment: @lubgr: Yes, consider refactoring to `.numberOfWives() + .numberOfHusbands()`; and consider the implications of unsigned type overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the name *count* be unified with other containers, such as *std::multimap* and *std::multisets*.